# Splitting an area to 2 equal columns in using css with Vaadin CssLayout

Tags: css, vaadin

I need to split a CssLayout line to 2 equal area, the first one will contain a textArea, the second one a table.

So i used this code :

```
@Override
        protected String getCss(Component c) {
            if (c instanceof TextArea) {
                return "width: 50%; float:left";
            }
            if (c instanceof Table) {
                return "width: 50%; float:right";
            }
            return null;
        }
```

The result is not compatible with what i want to get, see pictures below (Sorry I was obliged to delete the displayed texts)

[image: Current result]

Aimed result:

[image: the wanted result]

So how to do it with css.

Setting the height values:

```
 @Override
        protected String getCss(Component c) {
           if (c instanceof EsolifeTextAreaWordingLanguage) {
                return "height: 213px";
            }
            if (c instanceof Table) {
                return "height: 219px;padding-left: 8px"; 
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: It's a typical usecase for the `HorizontalLayout`, why not use this one?

Comment: Yes u're right but in my case i need to remove nested (Horizontal and Vertical layouts) for performance purpose. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that css layout has 100% width.

Then you must set text area and table width with setWidth(50, Unit.PERCENTAGE) method, but not with css code.

But If you want to set width with css then on text area and table call setSizeUndefined() method.

Comment: Hi @Dragan so from what i understood i have to call setSizeUndefined() method if i want to override the getCss method. Is there a way to set the width with the  setWidth(50, Unit.PERCENTAGE) method and the height in the getCss method because i have a specific percentage value to add in the height value?

Comment: You can set only height to be undefined with setHeight(Sizeable.SIZE_UNDEFINED, 0);

Comment: And in the same time i can set the height values in the getCss() methode you can see the added code above